# There is any way like append more data in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using knockoutjs to bind data, and I want to append data bind in one element.

Here is my code :

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-bind="foreach: people">
   <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
   <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
  </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
function getData(pageNumber)
{
   //code get data
   //binding
  ko.applyBindings({ peopla: obj }, document.getElementById('wrapper'));
}
```

In the first time the pageNumber is 1, then I call getData(1), and I want show more data in page 2 I will call getData(2), and in page 2 data will be show more in wrapper element like append in jquery.

If I use normal jquery I can call some like that

```
$("#wrapper").append(getData(2));
```

So I don't know how to use knockout bind more data in one elemnt

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script, this sort of simulates how you can append data to your array by replacing existing data or adding on to it. Hope it helps

```js
function myModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray([{
        name: 'Page 1 data',
        credits: 'credits for page 1'
    }]);

    var i = 2;

    self.getData = function () {
        var returnedData = [{
            name: 'Page ' + i + ' Name',
            credits: 'credits for page ' + i
        }];
        self.people(returnedData);
        i++;
    }
 self.getData2 = function () {
        var returnedData = {
            name: 'Page ' + i + ' Name',
            credits: 'credits for page ' + i
        };
        self.people.push(returnedData);
        i++;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-bind="foreach: people">
         <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>

        <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span>

        </p>
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click: getData">Simulate get data (Replaces current data)</button>
        <button data-bind="click: getData2">Append to the same array (Adds to existing array)</button>
```